# Reset div after clicking on link

Tags: html, angularjs

I have three links:

```
<h3><a href="" ng-click="setActive('housePointz')">Click here to give unitz to House</a></h3>
<h3><a href="" ng-click="setActive('memberPointz')">Click here to give unitz to House Member</a></h3>
<h3><a href="" ng-click="setActive('editTable')">Click here to edit unitz table</a></h3>
```

I want to display different data on each link click. for the first two links data hidden inside page. But for the third one I want to load data from another php page.

Code for displaying active link:

```
unity.controller("index", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile){
  $scope.setActive = function (name) { 
    $scope.thing = name; 
    if($scope.thing == 'editTable'){
      var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div my-Customer></div>")($scope);
      $("#d").append(compiledeHTML);        
    }else{ $("#d").append(''); }

  } //display active link
  $scope.isActive = function (name) { return ($scope.thing == name); } // Returns false if thing is different.
}])  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'House/unt_table.php'
    };
  });
```

And unt_table.php page:

```
<p>Test data</p>
```

It works fine except one problem. Every time i click on the link it keeps repeating data not overwriting it:

[image]

How can I overwrite displayed data each time link is clicked?

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. The `html()` will replace all the content in the `div` with the new content.

Comment: @karan3112 thank you

Comment: @karan3112: you can add this as anwer.. You deserve upvote for this.

Comment: @karan3112 yeah please add this as an answer I will mark it as correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

The `html()` will replace all the content in the div with the new content. More info on the [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/)